# Unable to set picture property in FacebookShareParams ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sharer

I am unable able to set the picture property in Facebook share params.

Every time I set it, it always remain `nil`:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:filePath];

    // Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
    params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
    params.name = @"Check if it works";
    params.caption = @"Yet to fix image capture and publishing it";
    params.picture = url;
```

What is the problem in there?

Comment: I am facing the similar problems

Comment: Did you find the solutions . I am facing same problem dude

Comment: Can you edit your post so that it will surface on top again

Comment: No i was not able to find any solution for this.

Comment: How did you do that then any ideas..